# R package clogitL1 no longer available?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, regularization

When I try to install `clogitL1` on my work server I get

```
Warning message:
package ‘clogitL1’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

I get the same warning message when I try to install it using previous versions of R.

At [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clogitL1/index.html) I see

```
Package ‘clogitL1’ was removed from the CRAN repository. 
Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive. 
Archived on 2018-06-17 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders.
```

**Questions**:
What's going on here?
It seems that this package can no longer be installed?
Is there still a way to install and use it?

I use this package extensively professionally.  We just had our servers upgraded and I would like to keep using this package...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to [install an archived version](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages) of the package.